# Boolean algebras/Unknown notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, model-theory, boolean-algebra, ordinals

Does someone know what is meant (in the context of trees and Boolean algebras by Shelah) [here](http://shelah.logic.at/nonstructure/VII.pdf) on the page 8 right above Remark 1.5:

$$\{\langle\rangle\}\cup\{\langle\xi\rangle\otimes_{\zeta(*)}d\eta:\xi\in w \text{ and }\eta\in I_\xi\}$$
?
I do not know what $d$ means in this notation, nor can I find it in the text.
All of the relevant notation (except for the questioned $d$) is given on the pages 8 and 9.

Comment: Please include more context in the body of the post, e.g. what the other letters and symbols denote.

Comment: It is a Shelah's style complicated paper dealing with Boolean algebras, ordinals and trees. All the definition could be found on the pages 8 and 9, but for $d$. I hope that someone might have an idea what it denotes.

Comment: User EvgenyMakarov on Math Help Boards might know this one.

Comment: Excellent, how do I contact him? I'm from time to time lost in Shelah's papers and a brief consultation would help me enormously.

Comment: I believe this is a typo and that the $d\eta$ should just be $\eta$. That this is a typo is reinforced by (2) in Remark 1.5, and the fact that the notation $d\eta$ (or $d(\text{anything})$ never appears in the rest of the paper. (And the fact that Shelah's papers aren't exactly renowned for their readability and lack of typos).

Comment: Just sign up for a free account at Math Help Boards, and post this in the Discrete Mathematics, Set Theory, and Logic subforum. He'll see it quite soon, I don't doubt.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I failed to finish my registration there due to some "human verification problems". Can I reach him otherwise for consultations with Shelah's work?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thank you for catching this for me.

Comment: I'm an admin there: what's your username?

Comment: Just create an account and send me an email with a password and username to (pax0@seznam.cz) Note, there is 0 not O after x in that email. Thank you.

Comment: He is not on these pages on math.stackexchange? Why?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Could you please send me that email with login possibilities to Math Help Boards?

Comment: @user122424: My apologies: please try to register again, and post your username and email here. If it doesn't go through, I can force it.